# Better solution to reloading the page inside a method in C#

Tags: c#, reload, windows-server-2012

Is there an easier or a more efficient way to reload a page that a control(which holds the method) is on then this code?

```
this.Page.Response.Redirect(this.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
```

Need to reload a session variable on another page for a balance that my control updates that balance from. So I run through the code save the session variable then hit the code above to reload. Seems to work locally as well as on 2008 Windows Severs but when I try it on the 2012 Server it says the page can not display that way. Is there a better solution to the reloading of that? Thanks

Comment: Not sure where the comment went that said I should use Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl); instead but that seemed to solve the issue I was having. thank you for who ever that was.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);